# Autosar Acceptance Test Diagnostic Services

Tags: autosar

I'm currently creating an acceptance test for Diagnostic Services.

How can I write a value to a memory of a DID?

Example Test Step:

> [SWC]
>
> Write 0x1A1B1C1D into memory of DID=0xFE88

[SWC] means that this step has to happen in the SWC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is the job of the Dcm to do the actual write to the DID. The Dcm has the ability to fetch values from an application software component over a port-based connection, but the software component can never directly write to a DID.

Therefore, you need to define A PortPrototype on the side of the application that feeds the value into a compatible PortPrototype exposed by the Dcm service-component,and the latter needs to be configured to put the received value into the correct DID.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, I am not an Autosar Expert or something, my job is just to implement Acceptance Test and I just rely on the SWS. Can I use the Callout 'Dcm_WriteMemory' for this test step?

Answer (score 1):

How can you access the test target? Can you debug it?

1. The first approach comes to my head is runs in debug, find the DID variable and modify value directly...
2. If debug port is not available, you may find the DID allocated address in map file and a simple hack program could implemented to prepare value by write value to that address.
3. If above not appropriate, you may use UDS 0x2E service (write data by identifier) to modify DID value. This approach require no any development but UDS service.